# How do I generate a network matrix from data I collect from the Twitter API?

Tags: matplotlib, twitter, redis, networkx

Kind of a Python noob here.  I have Python code from Matthew Russell's books "21 Recipes for Mining Twitter" and "Mining the Social Web" that I want to use for a project to collect various kinds of data from the Twitter API See his github page here: https://github.com/ptwobrussell

One thing I can't figure out is how to generate a network matrix/graph from the relationships between a user and his/her followers/friends.  So for example, here is his Python code for collecting the friends of a user on Twitter (also here: https://github.com/ptwobrussell/Recipes-for-Mining-Twitter/blob/master/recipe__get_friends_followers.py):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import twitter
from recipe__make_twitter_request import make_twitter_request
import functools

SCREEN_NAME = sys.argv[1]
MAX_IDS = int(sys.argv[2])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Not authenticating lowers your rate limit to 150 requests per hr. 
    # Authenticate to get 350 requests per hour.

    t = twitter.Twitter(domain='api.twitter.com', api_version='1')

    # You could call make_twitter_request(t, t.friends.ids, *args, **kw) or 
    # use functools to "partially bind" a new callable with these parameters

    get_friends_ids = functools.partial(make_twitter_request, t, t.friends.ids)

    # Ditto if you want to do the same thing to get followers...

    # getFollowerIds = functools.partial(make_twitter_request, t, t.followers.ids)

    cursor = -1
    ids = []
    while cursor != 0:

        # Use make_twitter_request via the partially bound callable...

        response = get_friends_ids(screen_name=SCREEN_NAME, cursor=cursor)
        ids += response['ids']
        cursor = response['next_cursor']

        print >> sys.stderr, 'Fetched %i total ids for %s' % (len(ids), SCREEN_NAME)

        # Consider storing the ids to disk during each iteration to provide an 
        # an additional layer of protection from exceptional circumstances

        if len(ids) >= MAX_IDS:
        break

    # Do something useful with the ids like store them to disk...

    print ids
```

So I have managed to successfully run this code with a given user as the primary user for the command line argument.  But how do I actually get this data into a matrix that I can then analyze, run formulas on (like centrality), etc...?  So far I have figured that I probably need to use a combination of packages which may include NetworkX, Redis, and Matplotlib, but the step of actually generating this matrix eludes me.

Comment: take a look at my different HUGE twitter visualisations: www.twittercensus.se/graph2013 www.finnishtwitter.com and www.twittercensus.dk - if you have questions, please ask!

Comment: Great visualizations.  Do you have a publicly available script that you use to gather the data?  What software language and packages do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in a database or file. Better choose according to what the software you will use to analyze the data supports.

Here is an example of a file in `.gdf` format, letting you store both nodes and edges data:

```
nodedef> id VARCHAR, label VARCHAR, followerCount VARCHAR
1623,jchris,5610
13348,Scobleizer,319673
21213,tlg,1141
...
edgedef> user VARCHAR,friend VARCHAR
1623,13348
1623,621713
...
```

The code you quoted in example does the part of extracting the edges, you still need another extraction step to extract the nodes.